# Linux : remove duplicate line

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, aix, uniq

I have a file txt. I would like to remove all duplicate line.

I tried these, but did not work

```
sort -ur file.txt
```

or

```
uniq -D -f 2 file.txt
```

file.txt

```
34.78.54.21 websrv1 nameweb
34.78.54.21 nameweb
```

I just need one line

Comment: That file has no duplicated lines. What do you need exactly?

Comment: please add the expected output and explain on what basis duplicate is defined... adding few more input cases would help as well

Comment: @Sundeep i need to sorting the ip adresse

Answer (score 1):

From your input I assume you are referring to the first field (34.78.54.21) as a duplicate. If you just want to keep the first occurrence of each number then this works for you:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file.txt
```

Output:

```
34.78.54.21 websrv1 nameweb
```

This command looks if $1 is not as a key in the array. If it is not then it will be added to the array and the default print will happen. For the next line $1 is in the array and the whole thing will evaluate to false and not print.